# How to save a temporary value in a security token?

Tags: python, security, token, m2crypto, pkcs#11

Is it possible to save a value in a security token memory by using PyKCS11 and M2Crypto?

I need to save an integer to token memory, so that the value can be carried out with the token

I know how to create objects, but is it possible to create attributes in a token, so whenever I read that attribute I will know the status of that token.

Comment: is it possible to save data using "cko_data" object? If yes, then how?

Answer (score 0):

using PKCS#11, the only way to store 'home made' data, it through the use of a CKO_DATA object type. Like any object, it can be persistent on the token (not lost when the token is powered off) or it can be a memory object (lost when the session to the token is closed).

To create a **CKO_DATA** object is similar to any other object creation:

- open a **r/w session** on the slot
- if the object is to be protected by user authentication (**CKU_USER**) then Login as user
- create the object template with mandatory attributes such as **CKA_CLASS** etc. (*refer to the PKCS#11 specifications for details*)
- set the **CKA_TOKEN** to **TRUE** if the object is to be persistent, or **FALSE** if it is a **memory** object
- set the **CKA_PRIVATE** to **TRUE* if you want this object to be read/writen only upon successfull user authentication or set it to **FALSE** if anybody can access it.
- set a **CKA_LABEL** and **CKA_APPLICATION** attributes with values you want to help you find the object next time
- set the **CKA_VALUE** attribute to the value you want (your integer)
- Call **C_CreateObject**, using this template will create the desired object.

HTH,